# Find Word Count"- My code doesn't work properly

Tags: java, find

"Find Word Count"- Instructions:
Given an input string (assume it's essentially a paragraph of text) and a
word to find, return the number of times in the input string that the word is
found. Should be case agnostic and remove space, commas, full stops, quotes, tabs etc while finding the matching word.

=======================

My code doesn't work properly.

```
`
String input = " It can hardly be a coincidence that no language on" +
                " Earth has ever produced the expression as pretty as an airport." +
                " Airports are ugly. Some are very ugly. Some attain a degree of ugliness" +
                " that can only be the result of a special effort. This ugliness arises " +
                "because airports are full of people who are tired, cross, and have just " +
                "discovered that their luggage has landed in Murmansk (Murmansk airport " +
                "is the only known exception to this otherwise infallible rule), and architects" +
                " have on the whole tried to reflect this in their designs. They have sought" +
                " to highlight the tiredness and crossness motif with brutal shapes and nerve" +
                " jangling colors, to make effortless the business of separating the traveller" +
                " for ever from his or her luggage or loved ones, to confuse the traveller with" +
                " arrows that appear to point at the windows, distant tie racks, or the current " +
                "position of Ursa Minor in the night sky, and wherever possible to expose the " +
                "plumbing on the grounds that it is functional, and conceal the location of the" +
                "departure gates, presumably on the grounds that they are not.";
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        String whichWord = "be";
        whichWord = whichWord.toLowerCase();
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while(lastIndex != -1){

            lastIndex = input.indexOf(whichWord,lastIndex);

            if(lastIndex != -1){
                count ++;
                lastIndex += whichWord.length();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
`
```

Comment: “My code doesn't work properly.” How can you tell?

Comment: Have you tried to use contains and substring instead?

Comment: @VGR What do you mean?

Comment: “My code doesn't work properly” is not an actual problem.  What, exactly, did you observe that led you to believe the code doesn’t work?  What did you expect to observe instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are not checking complete word. So, its matching both 'be' and 'because'. You're checking if there are any sub-strings contains the word 'be'. Could you please try below solution using regex? It will solve your purpose:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = " It can hardly be a coincidence that no language on" +
                " Earth has ever produced the expression as pretty as an airport." +
                " Airports are ugly. Some are very ugly. Some attain a degree of ugliness" +
                " that can only be the result of a special effort. This ugliness arises " +
                "because airports are full of people who are tired, cross, and have just " +
                "discovered that their luggage has landed in Murmansk (Murmansk airport " +
                "is the only known exception to this otherwise infallible rule), and architects" +
                " have on the whole tried to reflect this in their designs. They have sought" +
                " to highlight the tiredness and crossness motif with brutal shapes and nerve" +
                " jangling colors, to make effortless the business of separating the traveller" +
                " for ever from his or her luggage or loved ones, to confuse the traveller with" +
                " arrows that appear to point at the windows, distant tie racks, or the current " +
                "position of Ursa Minor in the night sky, and wherever possible to expose the " +
                "plumbing on the grounds that it is functional, and conceal the location of the" +
                "departure gates, presumably on the grounds that they are not.";

        input = input.toLowerCase();
        String whichWord = "be";
        whichWord = whichWord.toLowerCase();

        int count = 0;
        String regex = "(\\W|^)" + whichWord + "(\\W|$)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```